# Mdb file data insertion increase mdb size

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a Mdb file data inserting into mdb is working fine after insertion 
the size of Mdb file ex:200MB  is showing  when I open with ms office and close mdb file it decrease size to 14MB How to solve this problem

My code

```
ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
ADOX.Table table = new ADOX.Table();

table.Name = "StickerData";

table.Columns.Append("Centercode", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 30);
table.Columns.Append("Centername", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 210);

cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + dbPath + ";" + "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");
cat.Tables.Append(table);

using (OleDbConnection oldbcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + dbPath + ";" + "OLE DB Services=-4"))
{
    oldbcon.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            OleDbCommand oldbcmd = new OleDbCommand();
            oldbcmd.Connection = oldbcon;
            oldbcmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO StickerData([Centercode],[Centername]) 
                            VALUES (?,?)";
            oldbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            oldbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Centercode", reader["Centercode"].ToString());
            oldbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Centername", reader["Centername"].ToString());

            oldbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    oldbcon.Close();
    con.Close();
}
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cat.Tables);
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cat.ActiveConnection);
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cat);
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?  The decrease in size will be  Access compacting the database (I.e. rearranging reserved/fragmented space).

Comment: Assuming no data loss, this is a good thing. Sounds like db is set to run Compact & Repair automatically on close.

Comment: i actually when i inserting data into mdb it reaches more than 2GB at that time it give error like mdb  is corrupted or not connected but actually the size of data is not 2GB only 500MB